# Can't install TPLINK wireless adapter driver on Linux

Tags: linux

I have a TP-LINK Archer T2UH wireless adapter and i'm trying to install its driver by typing these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/Myria-de/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.git
cd mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916
make
sudo make install
sudo mkdir -p /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA
sudo cp RT2870STA.dat  /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/RT2870STA.dat
```

But when I type the `make` command:

```
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory '/quidam/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory '/quidam/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/tools'
/quidam/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/tools/bin2h
chipset = mt7610u
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /quidam/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/4.17.0-kali3-amd64/build SUBDIRS=/quidam/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.17.0-kali3-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:404: LINUX] Error 2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kali linux missing Linux headers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44520985/608639)

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410109/lib-modules-4-14-0-kali1-amd64-build-doesnt-exist-when-i-try-to-install-rtl881